# Android WiFi Direct client socket timeout

Tags: android, sockets

I'm new to Android, somewhat new to socket programming.  I have two devices, running `Android 5.1`, connected with WiFi direct (not sure if that's relevant).  I have a service where the server listens for a request on a socket, then returns a reply back to the client.

Likewise the client code sends a request and listens for the reply from the server.  The server is sending the response, but the client never gets the message and the socket times out.

Server test code:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "test waiting for a request");
        mServer = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket socket = mServer.accept(); //Block to receive message //
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Log.i(TAG, "Message received! " + in.readLine());

        String msg = "This is my reply.";
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println(msg);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket Accept Interrupted", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket Failure", e);
    } finally {
        if (mServer != null && mServer.isBound()) {
            try {
                mServer.close();
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close socket trying to recover from SocketException", ioException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client test code:

```
    Socket socket = null;
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(host, PORT);
    int socketTOms = 5000;
    try  {
        socket = new Socket(host, PORT);
        socket.setKeepAlive(false);
        String syncReq = "Request to server.";

        //Send Request//
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(syncReq.getBytes());
        socket.setSoTimeout(socketTOms);

        //Rcv reply//
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        Log.i(TAG, "Message received! " + in.readLine());

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Timeout while reading from socket: timeout=" + socketTOms);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
    } finally {
        if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception while closing socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm running the server and client on two different devices through Android Studio and can see in the logs that the server receives the request and sends the reply, but the client always `throws` `SocketTimeoutException`.  I saw else where that `socket.setKeepAlive(false)` would fix the problem, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Seems simple enough, but I can't see what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out .... 
On the client side I was using `outputStream.write(...)` to send the request to the server as in:

```
    String syncReq = "Request to server.";
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(syncReq.getBytes());
```

But reading it on the server with `BufferedReader.readLine()`:

```
    Socket socket = mServer.accept(); //Block to receive message //
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    Log.i(TAG, "Message received! " + in.readLine());
```

My problem was that `outputStream.write(...)` does not append a '\n' at the end of the String, but `in.readLine()` on the server expects it.  Therefore the server was blocking while waiting for '\n'; which in turn caused the client socket to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this line of code before infinite loop   mServer = new ServerSocket(PORT);

Did you try to create thread in sever side app. This makes the process to run in parallel so that while server is waiting for request the application does not gets hang. First of all try this code for localhost . To find Inetaddress just use InetAddress.getLocalHost(). Then run this. For communication with different devices there is service provided that is called (NSD) (Network Service Discovary).

But if you want to run this way I have written a code for you.

Server side code

```
 TextView textView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                connect();
            }
        }
);



    }


    public void connect()
    {

        MyServer myServer= new MyServer();
        myServer.setEventListener(this);
        myServer.startListening();

    }





    @Override
    public void Display(String message) {

        textView.setText("Client - "+ message);
    }
}
```

Client side code

```
 TextView textView;
    Button button;
    Thread mThread;
    Socket clientSocket;
Button sendBtn;
  public  String userText1;
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    EditText editText;
    Object userText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        sendBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
       editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        userText=editText.getText().toString();


                       start();
                    }
                }
        );




    public void start()
    {
       mThread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               try {
                   clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2001);
                   Log.v("binaya", "client socket created");
                   output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                   output.writeObject(userText);
                   Message serverObj = Message.obtain();
                   ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());


                   String strMsg = input.readObject().toString();
                   serverObj.obj = strMsg;

                   mHandler.sendMessage(serverObj);

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }


           }
       });
    mThread.start();
    }


     Handler mHandler= new Handler()
     {
         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             msgDisplay(msg.obj.toString());
         }
     };

    private void msgDisplay(String msg) {
    textView.setText("Server - " +  msg);

    }
```

We have used handler because we cannot touch user interface from inside runnable in this case. 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sháilèndra Wregmi